# Transparent Navigation Bar with blur TableView Scroll Offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create this effect.

Blur effect only on the scroll offset view

[image]

I tried to do this programmatically as follows

```
- (void)addBlurEffect {
    // Add blur view
    //    CGRect statusBarViewRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

    /*to extwnd from status bar till the end of navigation bar height*/
    CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y-40, self.frame.size.width, bounds.size.height+20);

    /*Make a blur view*/
    UIVisualEffectView *visualView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];

    /*Assign a tag to make it accessable from view hirarchy*/
    visualView.tag = 10000;

    visualView.frame = aRect;
    visualView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:visualView];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:42.0f green:152.0f blue:231.0f alpha:0.7f];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:visualView];

    /*back button was disabled following enables it*/
    visualView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
}
```

i am not able to recreate the UI. this is what i get 
[UIEffectView adds a gradient effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJv4I.gif)

a gradient effect and not a clear view. how shall i recreate the required UI effect?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :-
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);

Comment: i need to get the blur effect which you see above when i push in the table view under the navigation bar.
i get a gradient effect and not transparent which i have shared in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add a blur effect to view.

var blurEffectView : UIVisualEffectView!

```
func addblurEffectToView()
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        blurEffectView.alpha = 1
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
```